# Someone stole my minute :/

Tags: c#, time, timespan

I am trying to convert a time represented in double, something like `23.40` which means 23 hours and 40 minutes, using the following method:

```
private TimeSpan DoubleToTimeSpan(double time)
{
    double hour = Math.Floor(time);
    double minute = (time - hour) * 100d;
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan((int)hour, (int)minute, 0);
    return ts;
}
```

When testing it on some times, like `23.40` for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(DoubleToTimeSpan(23.40));
```

It shows `23:39:00`, a whole minute has been stolen by the system! Where is my minute?

**Note**: I know about `TimeSpan.FromHours`, this doesn't help me because this method considers the minutes as percentage, so `23.40` is 23 hours and 40% of an hour, which is `23:24:00`.

Comment: I would call the `Time Police` and file a report..

Comment: Doesn't 23.40 mean 23 hours and 40 minutes?

Comment: I don't know.  The last time the time police showed up, there was nothing but trouble -- http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JndR6LyDLRQ/T-O8YRHGQXI/AAAAAAAAEj8/kawuyzyoRRU/s400/sierra_087.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `0.4` cannot be exactly represented in the `Double` floating-point format, you get its nearest representation, which in the case of `(23.4-23)*100` is probably something like `39.999999999999858`. When you use `(int)`, you truncate the fraction, leaving you with 39.

You need to round instead of truncate, so use [`(int)Math.Round(minute)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use the `Decimal` type, which *can* exactly represent decimal numbers like `23.40`.

Comment: Some details. The decimal number `23.4` corresponds to binary `10111.{0110}{0110}{0110}...` where the block in braces recurs forever. A `double` has room for only 53 bits, so this gets rounded to nearest, that is
`10111.011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110`.
That's a ronud-down in this case.
(continued)

Comment: After subtracting decimal 23 from this, we are left with
`0.011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110000000`.
Remember that leading zeroes don't count towards the 53 bits limit. Note that this subtraction result ends with a bunch of zeroes. It is actually not so close to the best decimal `0.4` representation that a `double` can hold. This is what happens when you "subtract away" the most significant digits from a floating-point type. Compare with the `double` subtraction `9876543210.1 - 9876543210.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Try rounding it instead of int

```
private TimeSpan DoubleToTimeSpan(double time)
{
    double hour = Math.Floor(time);
    hour.Dump();
    double minute = (time - hour) * 100d;
    minute.Dump();
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan((int)hour, (int)Math.Round(minute), 0);
    return ts;
}
```

If you do just (int)minute it will take the integer part of your double.

Answer (score 0):

When you cast from a `double` to an `int`, it's truncating your value for minute -- thus your lost minute.

Answer (score 0):

```
(time - hour) * 100d
```

Will evaluate to 39.999999999999858, and thus 39 when casting to int.

Answer (score 0):

You've used Math.Floor for the hour, so use Math.Ceiling for the minute. It seems to work ok.

```
private static TimeSpan DoubleToTimeSpan(double time)
{
    return new TimeSpan((int)Math.Floor(time), (int)Math.Ceiling((time - Math.Floor(time)) * 100d), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to use decimals. This will prevent precision loss.

```
decimal minute = ((decimal)time)-((decimal)hour)*100;
```

Comment: I don't think it has a chance of preventing the precision loss. It was lost already when `23.40` was saved into the `double time`. You can't recover the lost bits.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a better solution, but if you're on .NET 4.0 or later, you can also go through a `string`. It seems like `"23.40"` is a sequence of characters with one interpretation as a `double`, and another one as a `TimeSpan`.

If you like that idea, use:

```
TimeSpan DoubleToTimeSpan(double time)
{
    string str = time.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(str, "h'.'mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return ts;
}
```

Maybe not as fast as the multiply-by-100-and-round approach, though I haven't tested that.